# WPF set Binding dynamically back to original state after changing Text property of textbox in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a couple of textboxes which are set with complex Databinding in WPF.
This works fine when just selecting items from a listbox in viewsource. (using Observable collection)

However, I am having an issue when I press a certain button I want the textboxes to become blank or contain a zero. So I set the .Text in C# to 0 or blank depending on the textbox. However it seems by doing that it also removes my bindings on this element. How can I get my bindings back in the original state through C#?

Xaml example

```
<TextBox Name="BandNrTextBox" Width="200" IsReadOnly="True">
    <TextBox.Text>
         <Binding Path="BandNr" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Mode="OneWay">
                                
         </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

After that I set the BandNr element in C#

```
BandNrTextBox.Text = "0";
```

Now when I select another option from my listbox normally it should get the correct value through the bindings again however it seems the Bindings are gone cause nothing appears in my textBlock.

Comment: You are right! Setting the `.Text` property again will break the binding. You need to change the value of `BandNr` instead. Is there a reason you can't change that value directly?

Comment: Yeah I need to be able to select items and show data in the textboxes through binding again after clearing the boxes

Comment: Just set BandNr = 0

Comment: @taquion don't really know what you mean but pretty sure that I have to adress the .Text property of the element otherwise it will give errors for sure :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a proper solution IMO, as you should be handling the values directly to achieve what you want. Turning the bindings on/off seems counter productive. With that said setting the `.Text` property changes the binding to a direct value. If you need to rebind you would do so like this.

```
Binding b = new Binding();
b.Source = YourViewModel; //Whatever contains BandNr
b.Path = new PropertyPath("BandNr");
b.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(BandNrTextBox, TextBox.TextProperty, b);
```

Also a heads up, you can simplify your XAML

```
<TextBox Name="BandNrTextBox" Width="200" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding BandNr, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Comment: Thx for the info. The reason i write my bindings like that is because i will implement validation templates later on so I will be forced to write them like that in the end. But If i understand correctly you would just make another form for the "new" value for the textboxes  and not mess with the bindings at all?

Comment: Just for sake of the question I decided to not mess with the Bindings after all and just create a different form all together for the other values. I can then easily collapse or make visible one of the 2 forms depending on the needs of the user.